# need to include school entity within classroom entity

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 lists School & Classroom like below,

```
public static class WebApiData
{
    public static List<School> GetAllSchools()
    {
        List<School> schools = new List<School>
        {
            new School
            {
                id = 1,
                name = "Fort Craig Elementary",
                principal = "Michelle Thorne"
            },
            new School
            {
                id = 2,
                name = "Edgewood Elementary",
                principal = "Audrey Hills"
            }
        };

        return schools;
    }

    public static List<Classroom> GetAllClassrooms()
    {
        List<Classroom> classrooms = new List<Classroom>
        {
            new Classroom
            {
                id = 1,
                name = "Mrs. Cox's 2nd Grade",
                teacher = "Beth Cox",
                school_id = 1
            },
            new Classroom
            {
                id = 2,
                name = "Mr. Elliott's Kindergarten",
                teacher = "Martin Elliott",
                school_id = 1
            },
            new Classroom
            {
                id = 3,
                name = "Mrs. Smith's 1st Grade",
                teacher = "Amanda Smith",
                school_id = 2
            }
        };

        return classrooms;
    }
}
```

Now I need to get all Classrooms along with entire school entity as a property of Classroom?

I tried join,

```
            var result = from l1 in classrooms
                     join l2 in schools
                         on l1.school_id equals l2.id
                     select l1;
```

But instead of single property of school, I need entire school entity as a property of classroom in projection result?

Thanks,

Comment: you can include l2 also in the select statement like `select new { l1, l2 })`

Comment: it will give me 2 list. but I want l1(classroom) which includes l2(school) as one property, thanks for reply

Comment: How does your `ClassRoom` structure looks like?

Comment: it's doesn't have school property?

Comment: In that case, you should define an anonymous type with the combination of Data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could do in a different way. Make School a property of Classroom, instead of having the id only .

Then you can do what you want and create a single list with all the information.

Or even better, make Classroom a property of School. That makes more sense from an object abstraction point of view. Then you can build a list of all the classrooms in a school easily.

```
 your School could look like this : 

public class School
            {
                public int Id { get; set; }
                public string Name { get; set; }

                public List<Classroom> Classrooms { get; set; }
            }
```

then you could instantiate your schools like this :

```
public static List<School> GetAllSchools()
        {
            List<School> schools = new List<School>
        {
            new School
            {
                 Id =1 ,
                  Name = "1",
                   Classrooms = new List<Classroom> { new Classroom { Id = 1, Name = "1"  }, new Classroom { Id = 2, Name = "2"  } }
            },
            new School
            {
                Id =2 ,
                  Name = "2",
                   Classrooms = new List<Classroom> { new Classroom { Id = 3, Name = "3"  }, new Classroom { Id = 4, Name = "4"  } }

            }
        };

            return schools;
        }
```

Comment: I added some code to show what I mean, does that help or you need more ?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

**Option 1**

Include both object in your `Select` statement, you have an anonymous type with two properties, one represents `ClassRoom` and other `School`.

```
    // Approach 1
        var results = from l1 in classrooms
                 join l2 in schools
                     on l1.school_id equals l2.id
            select new {l1, l2 };
```

**Option 2**

Create an anonymous data type with combined properties.

```
    // Appraoch 2
        var results = from l1 in classrooms
                 join l2 in schools
                     on l1.school_id equals l2.id
            select new {
                            Id= l1.id,
                            Name = l1.name,
                            Teacher = l1.teacher,
                            SchoolId = l2.id,
                            SchoolName = l2.name,
                            Principal = l2.principal
                       };
```

Check working [`Example`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/i8Km8C)